# In distributed TensorFlow training, what is a PS task? What does PS stand for?

Tags: tensorflow, distributed-computing

They are mentioned here: https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed, and in this YouTube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=la_M6bCV91M, but there's never any background given.

Answer (score 2):

ps is a Parameter Server - it is a logical implementation of a physical area (be it CPU, a remote server) which is in charge of creating and preparing Tensors for computation. This is why the term "ps task" is used - to mean a task that creates Tensors. An example of parameters could be variables which represent neural network weights.

The corresponding "worker" is in charge of taking Tensors and running computations on them. An example of a worker is a neural network training process running on GPU.

*Resources:*

- https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/208bea22f40e3e179e4f125e3beb8be3144895f5/site/en/tutorials/distribute/parameter_server_training.ipynb
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jKV53r9-H14&list=PLQY2H8rRoyvzIuB8rZXs7pfyjiSUs8Vza&index=8
  Starting 3:00
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=la_M6bCV91M
  Starting 5:10